# trouble using preg_match and directory names with $_GET using PHP

Tags: php, get, preg-match

I have a script that uses $_GET to retrieve directory names and appends it to a URL to retrieve files in a folder outside the webroot.

Here is my current code:

```
<php
$getdir = $_GET['dir'];
$getdoctype = $_GET['doctype'];
$dir = "/var/www/uploads/$getdir/$getdoctype";
$subdir1 = scandir($dir); /* This function sorts dirs */
$list = array_diff($subdir1,array(".","..","index.php"));
echo "<ol>";
foreach ($list as $file)
{
        if (!is_dir($file)) echo "<li><a href='https://example.ca/private/download_files.php?dir=$getdir&doctype=$getdoctype&filename=$file'>$file</a></li>\n";

}
echo "</ol>";
?>
```

I understand that using $_GET is very unsecure in this situation so I want to clean my $_GET variables with a preg_match function. I've been given this function from a user on this board and can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code with the function:

```
<?php
$getdir = $_GET['dir'];
$getdoctype = $_GET['doctype'];

// CLEANING GET VARIABLES 
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $getdir) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $getdoctype)) {
die('Bad parameter!');
}


$dir = "/var/www/uploads/$getdir/$getdoctype";
$subdir1 = scandir($dir); /* This function sorts dirs */
$list = array_diff($subdir1,array(".","..","index.php"));

echo "<ol>";
foreach ($list as $file)
{
        if (!is_dir($file)) echo "<li><a href='https://example.ca/private/download_files.php?dir=$getdir&doctype=$getdoctype&filename=$file'>$file</a></li>\n";

}
echo "</ol>";

?>
```

The get variables can contain spaces in the directory names. Also `%20` is an http escape string that can also be accepted. I just don't want hackers getting into my server.

I will also accept alternatives to $_GET in this implementation if you guys have any.

Comment: Use [urldecode](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) before cleaning your $_GET variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory name should start with `a-zA-z` according to regex and added `space,_,-` also valid

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
// Explanation 
// \s : new folder
// \_ : new_folder
// \- : new-folder

if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s\_\-]+$/', urldecode($getdir)) || 
     !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s\_\-]+$/', urldecode($getdoctype))) {
    die('Bad parameter!');
}
```

### Learning Resources:

[Essential Guide To Regular Expressions Tools, Tutorials and Resources](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/01/essential-guide-to-regular-expressions-tools-tutorials-and-resources/)

Comment: where would I go to learn more about regex's and how to code them? I have no idea that and underscore "_" means space.

Comment: @fixnode please check my updated answer, i have included the learning resources, and a little explanation.